# ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function:

```
  getalleventsserial() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.ns.eventsbyserial(params['id']).subscribe(
          notificcationserial => {
            this.notif = notificcationserial;
            this.isEmpty = (Array.isArray(this.notif)) ? true : false;
            console.log(this.isEmpty)
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Service.ts

```
public eventsbyserial(id: string): Observable<Events> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('id_device', id);
    urlSearchParams.append('token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString();
    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.eventsbyserial), body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(notiff => {
            return new Events(notiff);
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

Json with data:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "StatusMessage": "OK",
    "StatusDescription": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "datetime_device": "2018-09-04 12:09:00",
            "alarmtype_id": 11,
            "id_serial": "333",
            "acted": 0,
            "user_acted": null,
            "dtm_created": "2018-09-12 04:09:53",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "datetime_device": "2018-04-04 12:09:00",
            "alarmtype_id": 1,
            "id_serial": "42544",
            "acted": 0,
            "user_acted": null,
            "dtm_created": "2018-04-04 04:09:53",
        }
    ]
}
```

Json empty:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "StatusMessage": "OK",
    "StatusDescription": "No result"
}
```

In this function I can show if I have data or not.

In html I used this code:

```
<table *ngFor="let item of notif">
   <tr class="cell" style=" border-width: 3px" >{{item.name}}
   </tr>
</table>
```

Works good, but in console show this error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Any idea please, how to solution this error?

Comment: what's inside `notif`? the problem is that notif has not a .name property, but it contains an array with .name property

Comment: I edit my post. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This error generally occurs when `*ngFor` is given an **`Object`**. `*ngFor` only works on Iteratable data-structures(**`Array`** s).

Log `notif` to the console to check what exactly is an array inside the `notif` object.

Also, since this value is being fetched asynchronously, you might want to wrap the `table` in a `*ngIf` or else you'll get an error on the console.

**Update:**
In your template, you should be looping over `notif.StatusDescription`:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>datetime_device</td>
    <td>alarmtype_id</td>
    <td>id_serial</td>
    <td>acted</td>
    <td>user_acted</td>
    <td>dtm_created</td>
  </thead>
  <tr 
    class="cell" 
    style=" border-width: 3px"
    *ngFor="let item of notif.StatusDescription">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.datetime_device}}</td>
    <td>{{item.alarmtype_id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.id_serial}}</td>
    <td>{{item.acted}}</td>
    <td>{{item.user_acted}}</td>
    <td>{{item.dtm_created}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You won't have to do all of that(calling `.json()` on response) if you use `HttpClient` instead of `Http`

**Update 2:** There's an issue with your `getbyid.html`. `selectedRecipe` is an Object but you're using it as an array in your template. I'm not really sure why exactly are you using a table there. You could simply display the details like:

```
Serial: {{selectedRecipe.id}}
Serial: {{selectedRecipe.datetime_device}}
```

Here's an Updated StackBlitz for your [**Ref**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yufbtc?file=app/getbyid.html).

Comment: Please post the structure of `notif` in your question. You can log `notificcationserial` to the console and check which property inside it is actually an array.

Comment: I was actually asking you to post the structure of `notif` that you are getting from the API. Would it possible for you to create a stackblitz? You can create one here: https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. Hope that helps. I'd be able to help better if I had a StackBlitz Sample to work with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180654/discussion-between-siddajmera-and-w-site).

Comment: I think that the problem is in ts code, not in html

Comment: I ceate https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckrd2t?file=app/hello.component.ts Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The html, as @SiddAjmera post, is correct.

```
<table *ngFor="let item of notif.StatusDescription">
   <tr class="cell" style=" border-width: 3px" >{{item.name}}
   </tr>
</table>
```

Despite that, you should see nothing. That's because `item` only have this properties:

```
"id"
"datetime_device"
"alarmtype_id"
"id_serial"
"acted"
"user_acted"
"dtm_created"
```

Simply as that, there is no **name** property. If you change `{{item.name}}` in `{{item.id_serial}}` you will see your data correctly.

Comment: no no, It's my mistake `{{item.name}}` sorry, correct is `{{item.id_serial}}`. I try   `*ngFor="let item of notif.StatusDescription"` but doesn't show any data

Comment: I have made a simple stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fs5lha that's working. In the constructor i've simulated a delay with the `setTimeout`. then used a ngIf to show data only when you have it. You can try to edit your code in this way. Let me know!

Comment: I try like you example but for me doesn't work. I don't understand why!!

Comment: Mh, can you do a stack blitz so i can have a look?

Comment: Please can you see this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckrd2t?file=app/hello.component.ts  Thank you!